# entity_autocomplete field thats added by ajax is not working

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a field im adding to a node-edit form by ajax. the field is a simple taxonomy auto-complete field.

when I add it directly in my form_alter it works, but when it's added by ajax, The autocomplete is not there - the field looks and behaves as a simple text field.

I have edited my question and added my code.

```
 use \Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray;

function MM_field_widget_MW_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context){
        $element['display_id']['#ajax'] = [
          'callback' => 'getAjaxArgumentsFields',
          'wrapper' => $id . 'arguments',
          'method' => 'replace',
          'event' => 'change',
        ];
        $display_id = $element['display_id']['#default_value'];
        $element['options']['arguments'] = get_argument_fields($display_id); //Works, with entity_autocomplete working

}


function getAjaxArgumentsFields(&$form,  \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
      $display_id = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#value'];
      $fields = get_argument_fields($display_id);
      NestedArray::setValue($form, $array_parents, $fields);
      return  NestedArray::getValue($form, $array_parents); //Returns the exact same fields, but no autocomplete functionality- they appeare and behave like a regular text field
}

function get_argument_fields($display_id){
      $args_field = [];
      $argument_definition = get_argument_definitions($display_id);
      $args_field = [
              '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
              '#title' => $argument_definition['title'],//Taxonomy term
              '#target_type' => $argument_definition['type'],//taxonomy_term
              '#default_value' => '',
              '#selection_settings' = [
                     'target_bundles' => $argument_definition['bundles'],//voc_name
               ],
      ];
     $args_field['#prefix'] = '<div id = "' . $id . 'arguments' . '">';
     $args_field['#suffix'] = '</div>';
     return $args_field;
}
```

What do you guys think could be the reason?
Thank you!

Comment: The reason is that [EntityAutocomplete::processEntityAutocomplete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Element%21EntityAutocomplete.php/function/EntityAutocomplete%3A%3AprocessEntityAutocomplete/8.7.x) is not executed. Probably because you mean by "added by ajax" it was added in an ajax callback, which is not allowed. Keep the form element in the form alter hook and then only deliver it from the ajax callback.

Comment: yes it is it added in an ajax callback.  I have really spent the day trying to figure out what "only deliver it from the ajax callback" means. Can you give me a hint? My ajax in invoked by a change of a select field.

Comment: The ajax callback you invoke receives $form as argument. This contains the form element you put into the form build in the form alter hook, but it should look different now, because it is processed by then. This processed $form is what you can deliver to the client, either by returning parts of $form or by building an ajax command.

Comment: I have edited my question to add more code. because I feel that what you describe is what im doing. but I am sure im missing something.

Comment: In the ajax callback you overwrite the fields again with the unprocessed version of the form element.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, So thanks to [4k4](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/47547/4k4) I now understand what i was doing wrong, and for the favour of everyone that will meet this issue again:

The form_alter is invoked as well when ajax callback is invoked.
by the time the execution got to my ajax callback (getAjaxArgumentsFields) the form_alter has already altered my form, so all i had to do was return the fields without changing them.
Here is the code that worked for me:

```
use \Drupal\Component\Utility\NestedArray;

function MM_field_widget_MW_form_alter(&$element, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $context){
    $element['display_id']['#ajax'] = [
      'callback' => 'getAjaxArgumentsFields',
      'wrapper' => $id . 'arguments',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'event' => 'change',
    ];
    $display_id = $element['display_id']['#default_value'];
    $element['options']['arguments'] = get_argument_fields($display_id); //here I change my field, both on load of the page and also before ajax
}


function getAjaxArgumentsFields(&$form,  \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state){
    $array_parents =  clac the path to the wanted field 
    return  NestedArray::getValue($form, $array_parents);
}

function get_argument_fields($display_id){
      $args_field = [];
      $argument_definition = get_argument_definitions($display_id);
      $args_field = [
          '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
          '#title' => $argument_definition['title'],//Taxonomy term
          '#target_type' => $argument_definition['type'],//taxonomy_term
          '#default_value' => '',
          '#selection_settings' = [
                 'target_bundles' =>                     
           $argument_definition['bundles'],//voc_name
           ],
           ];
      $args_field['#prefix'] = '<div id = "' . $id . 'arguments' . '">';
      $args_field['#suffix'] = '</div>';
      return $args_field;
}
```